# check the position of values in JSON object array in php

Tags: php, css, arrays, json

I have a **JSON (Line A)** as shown below.

```
   $fp = fopen('../feeds/ptp-ess_landing.json', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, json_encode($output));
    fclose($fp);
    logActivity();

    if(file_exists('../feeds/ptp-ess_landing.json')){
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('../feeds/ptp-ess_landing.json'));
    }

    {"toggle_multi_tiles":["0","1"]}  // Line A
```

What I want is for the,

=> 1st value in JSON object array above at Line A, `animation-delay:0s;` is applied.

=> 2nd value, `animation-delay:4s;` is applied.

This is what I have tried:

```
    <?php
    if($data->toggle_multi_tiles[0]) {                 /* For 1st element */
    ?>
    .multi-tiles a:nth-of-type(1) {
        animation-delay: 0s;
    }

    <?php } ?>

    <?php
    if($data->toggle_multi_tiles[1]) {              /* For 2nd element */
    ?>
    .multi-tiles a:nth-of-type(2) {
        animation-delay: 4s;
    }

    <?php } ?>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I have used the if-logic above to *apply animation-delay of 0sec* onto the 1st value of JSON object array but the if condition will fail there as "0" is false. I am wondering what changes I should make in the php code above so that for

=> 1st value in JSON object array above at Line A, `animation-delay:0s;` is applied.

=> 2nd value, `animation-delay:4s;` is applied.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: I have modified my question. For the value in an array, animation-delay of 0 second should be applied and for 2nd it should be 4sec.

Comment: `if($data->toggle_multi_tiles[0])` this condition will not be true. I just want 0 second to applied for the 1st element in JSON object array.

Comment: I believe there is something wrong with my if block.

Comment: `"0"` is considered false, so the `if()` condition fails.

Comment: Yes, right it will fail.

Comment: So what's the problem? The `if` statement means it should only apply the CSS if the condition is true. It's not true, so it doesn't apply the CSS.

Comment: The problem is, for the `1st value` in JSON object array `animation delay of 0s` should always be applied and for the `2nd value` it should be `4s`.

Comment: Probably we have to use something else apart from if statement.

Comment: It sounds like you don't need an `if` statement at all.

Comment: Yes, I think so. I started with an if statement thinking that it would work but I believe its a wrong approach.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need any kind of conditional. Just output the CSS normally.

Comment: Also, 1st value in JSON object array can be `{"toggle_multi_tiles":["1","2"]}` It totally depends what we are saving there.

Comment: How does that affect what the CSS should look like?

Comment: Maybe you need to loop over all the elements of the array, and generate different CSS depending on the values?

Comment: Yes, it would not effect the CSS. Just giving you more information.

Comment: So is there any relationship between the JSON object and CSS?

Comment: Yes that's what I was trying to apply in css if through if block.

Comment: What is the relationship between them? Does the value in the array affect the delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should be looping through the array.

```
foreach ($data->toggle_multi_tiles as $i => $value) {
?>
.multi-tiles a:nth-of-type(<?php echo $i+1; ?>) {
    animation-delay: <?php echo 4 * $value; ?>s;
}
```

So when the array element is `0` you get `0s`, when it's `1` you get `4s`, when it's `2` you get `8s`, and so on.

Comment: Hi, I hope all is well. I have one [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58192780/how-to-check-if-a-date-falls-between-two-days-of-a-week), its not similar. I am wondering if you can have a look.